# Defining global variables in perl Mason Framework

Tags: perl, mason

I recently came across a problem: how to define a global variable in perl Mason Framework ? I need to define a variable and assign a value to it which will be visible from all Mason components, but all my attempts happen to be unsuccessful, because components tell that they don't see the variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to declare the global variables in the [allow_globals](http://www.masonhq.com/docs/manual/Params.html#allow_globals) parameter in your Apache config or when you build your Mason interpreter object.

Example when using a Mason interpreter object:

```
my $interp = HTML::Mason::Interp->new(
    ...,
    allow_globals => [
        '$global',
    ],
);
```

Example with Apache config:

```
PerlAddVar MasonAllowGlobals $global
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to make changes in Apache config. Could you please give some code example about how to build Mason interpreter object and use alow_globals in it ?

Comment: If you are running Mason under Apache, then you need to change the Apache config to add a new global variable.

Comment: Isn't Mason only available to use under Apache ? I'm pretty sure it's possible, but I'm new to Mason and can't find any notes on this question in the documentaiton.

Comment: No you can create an interpreter object and call a component without using Apache.